# How to reset local state with hooks in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a filter on the drawer and want to **reset state** when the *drawer is closed*. There are filters by number of people, type of activity or input value.

This is the local state.

```
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState<string>("");
      const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(1);
      const [checkedFilters, setCheckedFilters] = useState<string[]>([]);
```

This is the filter.

```
  const activities = useMemo(() => {
    return allActivities.filter(
      (item) =>
        item.participants >= count &&
        item.activity.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)
    );
  }, [count, searchQuery, allActivities]);
```

Comment: how are you closing the drawer ? Do you have any state which keeps track of the drawer's open and closed state ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the already given answers a bit more complete, if you want to reset all filters at once, I suggest to add a function as such:

```
function resetAllFilters() {
  setSearchQuery("");
  setCount(1);
  setCheckedFilters([]);
}
```

You can now call `resetAllFilters()` when you want to reset all the filters, like so:

```
<button onClick={resetAllFilters}/>Clear</button>
```

And in your case, you can use the function in the same way as event that is called when the drawer closes.

Answer (score 1):

**To resetting state, you just need to set it back to empty or your predefined state:**

```
setSearchQuery("");
```

**AND/OR**

```
setCheckedFilters([]);
```

**AND/OR**

```
setCount(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

To know how to reset `state`, first you need to know what is the initial value for each and every `state`

```js
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState<string>(""); // initial value is ""
const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(1); // initial value is 1
const [checkedFilters, setCheckedFilters] = useState<string[]>([]); // initial value is []
```

After knowing the initial value, you just need to invoke `setState` with initial value as below

```js
setSearchQuery("");
setCount(1);
setCheckedFilters([])
```